# Using URLEncoder.encode() to encode text that is going to be sent through REST

Tags: java, iphone, character-encoding

I am sending text message to my phone through a SMS gateway. I send them using REST, so I am just building my request and sending it with HttpClient.

```
String encodedUrl = host + URLEncoder.encode(text,"utf-8").
```

Here, text corresponds to the text I am sending through the gateway.

Everything works fine, the SMS is received properly. My iPhone displays the carriage returns and proper formatting. However, other phones like Blackberry or Windows phone display the text message without any carriage return or formatting.

Comment: What formatting are you referring to?  As for carriage return, not all phones understand CR character in SMS, so they may simply ignore it.

Comment: Check whether you use CR or CRLF for new line markers. Windows phones may require the latter.